# I need a program in PHP, where I search a number in a series mentioned and then give output as the index on which it is present?

Tags: php

I need a program in PHP, when I search a number in a given series like 1,3,7,15,31... and if it is present in the series then give output as the index on which it is present in series?

LIKE I HAVE DONE SOMETHING TO DO THIS BUT FAILED.

```
  <?php

       function test1($n) {
          for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i=$c) {
              $c =1 + (2 * $i);
          }
       }

       function test2($p) {
          global $c,$n;
          $input=array(1);
          $in=array_push($input,$c);
          $k=array_search($p,$input);
          $flipped = array_flip($k);
          var_dump($flipped);
        }

      test1(1000000);
      test2(45);
```

Like in this program I had made two `functions` and in `FUNCTION test1` I made a formula to make the series `1,3,7,15,31,63,127....` and in `FUNCTION test2` I insert a number in form of parameter and want to `SEARCH` that number in the series that I form above and the I want **OUTPUT** as the index of that number searched.

**Also** if the number is not present in the series then I want the output as the nearest number of the number I search.

HELP.!!!

Thank You

Comment: The function `test1` doesn't do anything. It merely wastes a bit of processor time!

Comment: Yeah I got your point sir. Ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a few problems with this code.

```
   function test1($n) {
      for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i=$c) {
          $c =1 + (2 * $i);
      }
   }
```

The first problem here is that you don't do anything with `$c` each time you increment it. You should probably be pushing it into an array of series integers.

Secondly you don't return a result, so you can't actually use the series you would've created.

You could use something like this instead:

```
function test1($limit) {
    $series = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $limit; $i = $i * 2 + 1) {
        $series[] = $i;
    }
    return $series;
}
```

Next, your `test2` function:

```
   function test2($p) {
      global $c,$n;
      $input=array(1);
      $in=array_push($input,$c);
      $k=array_search($p,$input);
      $flipped = array_flip($k);
      var_dump($flipped);
    }
```

Ok, first don't use global variables. Pass the ones you need in as arguments and again, return the result. To be perfectly honest, I'm not entirely sure what this function is supposed to do. All you need is the `array_search` call which ["searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful"](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php).

For example:

```
function test2($series, $number) {
    return array_search($number, $series);
}
```

Using these, you can do something like this:

```
$series = test1(1000000);
var_dump(test2($series, 45)); // bool(false)
var_dump(test2($series, 31)); // int(4)
```

---

> Also if the number is not present in the series then I want the output as the nearest number of the number I search.

Ok, you'll need to write some custom logic for this. I suggest you run your `array_search` check, then if it returns false you loop through your series and check the following criteria:

- The previous series entry is lower than your number
- The next series entry is higher than your number

Then return whichever of those two has a smaller absolute difference when you subtract the series entry from your number.

I'm not going to write an example for this because it smells a bit like a school assignment, which I'm sure you're capable of doing =) good luck.

Comment: Thank You so much for the help.

Comment: Most of what is written here is very good advice. However, that last thing the OP asks is:  "Also if the number is not present in the series then I want the output as the nearest number of the number I search.". `array_search()` isn't going to do that.

Comment: @BenHillier yeah, I just noticed that - have edited my answer. Thanks

Comment: There is some problem as here,
`$s=test1(100);
var_dump(test2($s,31));`

in test1 I have given limit 100 but then also if I give a number greater than 100 in test2, it do not give any error. It gives output.
**WHY...???**